# How to implement Play2 API server returning File via Ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, scala, playframework

I am using Scala Play2 framework and trying to convert SVG String data to other file types such as PDF,PNG,JPEG and send it to Client as a file.

What I want to achieve is that

1. client send Data via Ajax(POST with really huge JSON)
2. server generates a file from the JSON
3. server returns the file to the client.

But It seems that It's hardly possible that sending a file and let clients save it as a static file, So I am planning to make new static files on clients request and returns its access url to client side and open it via Javascript. and after clients finish the downloading, delete the file in a server though,In this approach, I have to

```
def generateFile = {
 ...
 ...
 outputStream.flush() // save the file to a disk
}
```

and

```
Ok.sendFile(new File("foo.pdf"))
```

I need to write and read file to a storage disk. and I do not think this is a efficient way.

Is there any better way to achieve what I want?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So, do I understand you correctly? 1) You want to send JSON to your Play server via AJAX. 2) Play then generates a file out of  the JSON data and stores it somewhere in the public assets folder. 3) Play returns the URL of this generated file to the client. 4) Then the client can download the file with the URL via a GET. 5) Play deletes the file after the download finishes. Correct?

Comment: @Kris almost right as you mentioned but one point, I didn't think to store JSON file but generated file itself.

Comment: But if we are talking about different requests here, then you have to store the file somewhere (e.g. file system). The first, the AJAX request, generates the file, the second lets you download that file. Since your server is stateless you have to store the file somewhere.

Comment: @Kris Sorry I was misreading what you said,what you mentioned in your first comment are exactly what I am trying to achieve.(I thought you said saving JSON itself to server and generating Files at a client's second request.)

Comment: I also can't see a different solution than storing the file temporarily in the file system (it's a file - that's what the file system is for, right :)). Why do you think it's not a good solution?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think this is not efficient enough?

I've seen a similar approach in a project:

- Images are converted and stored in an arbitrary tmp directory using a special naming scheme
- A dedicated server resource streams images to the client
- A system cronjob triggered every 5 minutes deletes images older than 5 minutes from the tmp directory

The difference was that the image data (in your case the SVG string) was not sent by the client but was stored in a database.

Maybe you could skip the step of writing images to disk if you're conversion library is able to generate images in memory.